# WPF FrameworkElement in GridView - update column width

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, custom-controls

I have a GridView. In one column a CustomControl (derived from FrameworkElement) is in the DataTemplate.

According to some interaction the CustomControl will changed its Width. How can I achieve, that the GridViewColumn changes it's Width dynamically to the Width of the widest CustomControl?

Comment: Unless I misunderstood your question, just set Width="Auto" on the gridviewcolumn.

Comment: Width="Auto" only works, when the Width of the CustomControl is set in advance. But if the Width is changed due to user actions, the Column does not resize anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the `SizeChanged` event of the control and set the `Width` of the `GridViewColumn`:

```
private void TextBox_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement ctrl = sender as FrameworkElement;
    theColumn.Width = ctrl.ActualWidth + 20;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<GridViewColumn x:Name="theColumn">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:TheResizingControl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

The control nor the framework won't do this for you. You need to write some code that does this.